# Pandas replacing values depending on prior row

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, replace, duplicates, cumsum

I'm pretty new to pandas and would like your input on how to tackle my problem. I've got the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ["me","you","you","me","me","me","me"],
                'B' : ["Y","X","X","X","X","X","Z"],
               'C' : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
              })
```

I need to transform it based on the row values in column A and B. The logic should be that as soon as values in column A and B are the same on consecutive rows, the first row in this sequence should be maintained but following rows should have an 'A' set in column B.

For example: Values in column A and B are the same in row 1 and 2. Value in column B row 2 should be replaced with A. This is my expected output:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'A' : ["me","you","you","me","me","me","me"],
                'B' : ["Y","X","A","X","A","A","Z"],
               'C' : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sum columns `A` and `B`:

```
a = df.A + df.B
```

Then compare with shifted version:

```
print (a != a.shift())
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool
```

Create unique groups by `cumsum`:

```
print ((a != a.shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    4
dtype: int32
```

Get boolean mask where values are duplicated:

```
print ((a != a.shift()).cumsum().duplicated())
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Solutions for replace `True` values to `A`:

```
df.loc[(a != a.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(), 'B'] = 'A'
print (df)
     A  B  C
0   me  Y  1
1  you  X  2
2  you  A  3
3   me  X  4
4   me  A  5
5   me  A  6
6   me  Z  7
```

---

```
df.B = df.B.mask((a != a.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(), 'A')
print (df)
     A  B  C
0   me  Y  1
1  you  X  2
2  you  A  3
3   me  X  4
4   me  A  5
5   me  A  6
6   me  Z  7

print (df2.equals(df))
True
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's perfect.